# Can we developp a web application with SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Well,I need to develop a web application with sql server so I choose spring boot Framework ,but the question is Can I use this Framework for both front and back end .

If not ,why ? and which technologie to add?

Also if you can help me with applications demo or tutorials in springBoot

Comment: [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) is a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The documentation fully covers this, look at the WebMVC section of the Spring Boot Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc

Out of the box it supports several template engines, I prefer Thymeleaf if I'm doing an all-in-one app.  Here's a good demo for using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/.

Also, if you decide to use this, read the documentation on Thymeleaf at https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html, it's an incredibly powerful templating engine and has a lot of features.